# Restore a local git directory with uncommitted changes

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a remote repository on GitHub, and I used to have a local git repository/directory on my Mac that works with the remote.

Last week, my hard drive was wiped out but fortunately I have a backup of the local git directory and it contains uncommitted changes.

How should I restore this directory so that: 1. all the branch-trackings are back; 2. uncommitted changes are preserved?

I'm using `git 1.8.5.2`.

Comment: You could simply replace the `.git` folder of a new clone with that of the backup - any config changes or local branches can be recovered then too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your folder isn't a git repo, but just contains the sources (with some of them modified), you can simply:

- clone again your GitHub repo
- use the `--work-tree` option to refer temporarily to your backup folder

That is:

```
git clone https://yourAccount@github.com/yourAccount/yourRepo
cd yourRepo
git --work-tree=/path/to/yourBackup add -- .
```